# django query to use annotate with a filter for each annotations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following database model -

```
class ObjectDetail(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    img = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uploaded_by')


class Vote(models.Model):

    vote_type = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    voted_by =  models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='voted_by')
    voted_for = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='voted_for')
    shared_object = models.ForeignKey(ObjectDetail, null=True, blank=True)
    dtobject  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, in my views I want to get the number of upvotes and downvotes for each of the objects.

One way of doing it would be to add a function under **class ObjectDetails**
as follows -

```
    @property
    def upvote(self):
        upvote = Vote.objects.filter(shared_object__id = self.id, 
                             vote_type = True).count()
        return upvote

    @property
    def downvote(self):
        downvote = Vote.objects.filter(shared_object__id = self.id, 
                               vote_type = False).count()
        return downvote
```

But this would, cause two queries for each of the object, present in the database. 
Another method would be to use `annotate`

```
obj = ObjectDetail.objects.select_related().filter(FILTER_CONDITION).annotate(upvote=Count('vote'), downvote=Count('Vote')).order_by('-shared_time')
```

The above statement is wrong in a sense that it just gives me the counts of votes, irrespective of upvotes and downvotes.

if you see into the model, you can get upvote by filtering `vote__vote_type = True` and a downvote by `vote__vote_type=False`

How to add these two conditions/filters in the query statement?

So my prime objective is to get the two values of `upvote` and `downvote` for each of the items, with making least db queries, such that in the template, if i do

{{ obj.upvote }} I can get the number of upvote on the object, and the similar for downvote.

Please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `values()` to group the different `vote_type`s?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values

```
Vote.objects.select_related().filter(FILTER_CONDITION).values('shared_object', 'vote_type').annotate(vote_count=Count('vote_type'))
```

At this point you can use `regroup` in the template to loop on `ObjectDetails`s

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: as you can see, i have two things, `upvote` and `downvote` so i need two different values, based on the filter. you have mentioned only one.

Comment: From what I understood you want to do something like `COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name GROUP BY vote_type` and the purpose of `values()` should be precisely this one.

Comment: i have edited the question, please re-read it thanks, for your help.

Comment: I edited my answer, now the `Vote`s are counted correctly but you don't loop through `ObjectDetail`s. Unfortunately I don't see any other way to get them with only one query.